# Can Standard .NET CMS systems be made to work with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

Has anyone successfully used a CMS developed for standard ASP.NET with ASP.NET MVC?

I currently use Immediacy CMS and it seems to be quite tightly coupled with standard ASP.NET, but I'd really like to start using ASP.NET MVC.

Are there any CMS systems out there directed at MVC?

How could I persuade my employer to move to ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest take a look to Kooboo ([kooboo.com](http://www.kooboo.com)), a simple to use but powerful for developers. Well documented API and based upon ASP.NET MVC (of course ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[N2 CMS](http://www.n2cms.com) has an [example site](http://n2.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24776) in ASP.NET MVC that I've been playing around with that works quite nicely - note that the code is now hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/n2cms/).

The problem you've got is that many CMS' already do a lot of "routing" in that the pages you are requesting/editing don't actually exist on disk, but are all in a data store of some kind, and there's an HttpHandler or ISAPI Filter sitting in front of ASP.NET to intercept the requests and work out what should be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally seen any of the big name CMS systems out there upgraded yet to take advantage of many of the new things the .NET framework offers, let alone start working on the MVC framework.

As with all things, a cost-benefit analysis is the best way to convince your boss to do anything. If you can point how how moving towards the MVC framework is going to make some immediate positives (as well as many long term positives) that can outweigh the costs (in time, energy, and money) in the switchover, then you have succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC are very different beasts in terms of how you develop applications on top of them. Technically, an ASP.NET MVC application is an ASP.NET application with some generic handler that invokes the core MVC framework.

The ASP.NET MVC framework is also relatively new (1.0 just released last MIX) and so it'll take a while before becoming mainstream.

How you can persuade your boss? Talk to him about the positive sides of ASP.NET MVC, and how it will improve his future business. There's plenty of material available to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of work using Immediacy (I used to work there) and I had thought about doing the same thing a couple of months ago.  I think that the main issues would result from things like the plug-in handler, the idoc handler and (if your still using it) the ilink hander.

When you enable things like friendly URLS I think this would cause issues if you had similar named methods in your controller actions.

You may be able use some MVC in your project, I could see  it working as an admin add-in  but I couldn't see it being used to usefully in the main webroot.

I would think a CMS would have to be built using MVC in mind to get the most benefits from using the pattern, instead of trying to make it work in parallel with a pre-existing system API (limited as it is) and making more work for yourself.